# Error while trying to connect via SSH

Tags: ssh, connection, localhost

After running the command:

```
ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost
```

I am getting an error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Please run again with `-vv`, i.e. `ssh -p 8101 -vv karaf@localhost`. Is the ssh server on localhost configured to listen on port 8101?

Comment: Yes it's working I am able to open Opendaylight

Comment: I don't know what Opendaylight has to do with this but please show the output of `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ssh`.

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:51386         127.0.0.1:8101          ESTABLISHED 1000       42450       8436/ssh

Comment: @pranav please [edit] your question to add extra information. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss, impossible to format correctly and can be deleted without warning. All information needs to be in the question.